# How does operating system keep track of object positions on the display?

Tags: display, mouse, operating-systems

I know the display using standards like VGA can be viewed as a matrix of pixels at least to the operating system. But modern displays include complex UI controls like buttons and text boxes.
I do not know if the OS does all the work or is it something provided by mouse technology out of box.

> The question now is, how does the OS keep track of the positions of
>   these controls so as to control programmatically.

Comment: This question is way to general and partly ambiguous. Are we talking about the interactions of the GPU rendering pipeline? Are we talking about buffers? Are we talking about windowing systems or widget rendering? Would you count applications that use operating system features to render application widgets "handled by the OS"? You're asking something very technical in a super vague way.

Comment: @jdwolf Yes you are right this question is too generic. And you touch on something that I was trying to ask. `widget rendering`. Widgets are bound to their software by events e.g click. How is the positioning of the widgets implemented. How does OS determine which widget to receive the event from mouse pointing.

Comment: I understand there is a lot of abstraction in play and I won't understand it all in one explanation.

Comment: You should maybe ask that question specifically in a new question. But as a teaser widget toolkits like Qt and GTK+ do a lot of their own rendering and will use the GPU for acceleration before passing off a reference the rendered content to the operated systems libraries and display server as buffer in a lot of cases. They can mutate a widget the OS partially renders. Most toolkits don't use X widgets directly because every property has to be updated with messages to reposition any widget but widgets can be moved relative to their parent etc.

Answer (score 2):

Button coordinates, button dimensions and mouse pointer coordinates are stored in memory. When user presses a mouse button, OS compares position of mouse pointer with positions of UI controls and determines appropriate action.

Display standards and drawing are unrelated, it's a purely mathematical operation.

Comment: close to mental picture I had

Answer (score 1):

You have screen coordinates and "Windows" (Rectangles), so you can always find out which object "owns" the pixel your pointer is currently at, just recursively iterate through the structures to check.

```
+---------------------+
+      +------+       +
+      +  X   + +--+  +
+      +------+ +  +  +
+               +--+  +
+---------------------+
```

The Windows can be hierarchical and cascading. E.g. GUI Elements are nothing but subwindows in this context. The OS will start from a root (which has a list of all "root level" windows) and will therefore be able to match the mouse position against all rectangles. Then it checks if the rectangle is in the foreground/has focus, etc. Then is repeats the same checks with the "Windows" (GUI elements) inside that window. Eventually it just calls the event handler function associated with the lowest level GUI element.